# The loss function doesn't go down in RNN when the input steps is variable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Update: I have re-written the question and remove the unnecessary codes. Thanks for the kind and timely comments.

I wanna use RNN for series prediction based on tensorflow. In details, I use a set of sentences as the training set in RNN based on tensorflow. For one sample i.e., one sentence, the output (the label) is the last word of the sentence and the input is the left part of the sentence.

I use serveral sentences for training. After trained, I use the inputs of the training set as input to predict the next word.

When the lengths of the sentences (series) are the same, the model works well. No problem at all.

When the legnths of the sentences (series) are different, I use the parameter **sequence_length** in tensorflow to enable variable-length series prediction, as follows.

```
tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_length)
```

But it doesn't work. The loss function keeps at a relatively high value and can not go down to nearly 0. The prediction result is bad.

The code is below.

```
import jieba
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# sentences for training
sentences = ["大家讨厌狗", "我讨厌蜘蛛", "他喜欢狗", "他语文好", "我喜欢猫", "他名字是小明"]

word_list = []
for sen in sentences:
    sent = list(jieba.cut(sen))
    print(sent)
    word_list += sent  # split Chinese sentences to words
word_list = list(set(word_list))  # remove the duplicated words

# word:id
word_dict = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(word_list)}  # word2id
print(word_dict)

# id:word
number_dict = {i: w for i, w in enumerate(word_list)}  # id2word

# total number of words
n_class = len(word_dict)
print(n_class)


n_hidden = 10           # number of units in hidden layer


# get batch of the input and output
def make_batch(sentences):
    input_batch = []
    target_batch = []

    inputs = []
    targets = []

    for sen in sentences:
        word = list(jieba.cut(sen))
        input = [word_dict[n] for n in word[:-1]]
        target = word_dict[word[-1]]

        inputs.append(input)
        targets.append(target)

    input_length = [len(x) for x in inputs]
    print(input_length)
    max_input_length = max(input_length)

    tot = 0
    for input, target in zip(inputs, targets):
        # one-hot encoding
        x = np.eye(n_class)[input]

        # make sure the inputs are the same length in style by appending extra zeros to the shorter inputs.
        if input_length[tot] < max_input_length:
            for k in range(max_input_length-input_length[tot]):
                x = np.append(x, [np.zeros(n_class)], axis=0)

        input_batch.append(x)
        target_batch.append(np.eye(n_class)[target])
        tot += 1

    return input_batch, target_batch, input_length, max_input_length


input_batch, target_batch, input_length, max_input_length = make_batch(sentences)
n_step = max_input_length             # time step (series length)

# a function that transfers X to a word
def transferX(input_batch):
    for i in range(len(input_batch)):
        L1 = list(input_batch[i])
        for x in L1:
            for j, e in enumerate(list(x)):
                if e != 0:
                    print(number_dict[j], end=' ')
            print()
    print('######################################')

# a function that transfers Y to a word
def transferY(target_batch):
    for i in range(len(target_batch)):
        L2 = list(target_batch[i])
        for j, e in enumerate(L2):
            if e != 0:
                print(number_dict[j], end='  ')
    print('######################################')


# transferX(input_batch)
# transferY(target_batch)

# set placeholders for input X and output Y
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_step, n_class])  # [batch_size, n_step, n_class]
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_class])  # [batch_size, n_class]

# set weights and biases
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_class]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_class]))

seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

# define the hidden layer which has n_hidden units
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(n_hidden)

outputs_, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_length)

# outputs = contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=outputs_, num_outputs=n_class, activation_fn=None)
outputs1 = tf.transpose(outputs_, [1, 0, 2])  # [n_step, batch_size, n_hidden]  2*3*5
outputs = outputs1[-1]  # [batch_size, n_hidden]             3*5

# define the model
model = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b  # model : [batch_size, n_class]           3*7

# define cross entropy as the cost
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=model, labels=Y))
# set Adam as the optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)

# the prediction result
prediction = tf.cast(tf.argmax(model, 1), tf.int32) # get the class id with the highest probability
# prediction = model  # get all the classes and the corresponding probabilities

# get a session of tensorflow
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

seq_length_batch = np.array(input_length)
print('the real length of each sample', seq_length_batch)


# training
for epoch in range(5000):
    _, loss = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: input_batch, Y: target_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch})
    if (epoch + 1) % 1000 == 0:
        print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost =', '{:.6f}'.format(loss))

# use the trained model to predict the next word (the last word of a sentence).
# The input is the input of the training set.
result = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: input_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch})

# We should get the exact right word, hopefully. But we don't.
print(result)
print([number_dict[x] for x in result])
```

The results of the code are as follows.
[image: resuls of the code]

The text version of the results are listed below in case the picture can not be accessed.

```
Loading model cost 0.601 seconds.
['大家', '讨厌', '狗']
Prefix dict has been built succesfully.
['我', '讨厌', '蜘蛛']
['他', '喜欢', '狗']
['他', '语文', '好']
['我', '喜欢', '猫']
['他', '名字', '是', '小明']
{'小明': 0, '蜘蛛': 1, '狗': 2, '好': 4, '是': 6, '猫': 7, '他': 8, '我': 9, '大家': 3, '名字': 5, '讨厌': 12, '喜欢': 11, '语文': 10}
13
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
2019-12-02 20:12:11.268252: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
the real length of each sample [2 2 2 2 2 3]
Epoch: 1000 cost = 1.678513
Epoch: 2000 cost = 1.323996
Epoch: 3000 cost = 1.202595
Epoch: 4000 cost = 1.156494
Epoch: 5000 cost = 1.135540
[2 2 2 2 2 0]
['狗', '狗', '狗', '狗', '狗', '小明']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank you for your time :)

Update: When I change the max training steps from 5000, as I set in the above code, to 50000, the resuts are below. You can see the loss keeps going down but with an unacceptable slow speed.

```
Loading model cost 0.627 seconds.
['大家', '讨厌', '狗']
Prefix dict has been built succesfully.
['我', '讨厌', '蜘蛛']
['他', '喜欢', '狗']
['他', '语文', '好']
['我', '喜欢', '猫']
['他', '名字', '是', '小明']
{'大家': 0, '语文': 2, '小明': 4, '是': 6, '讨厌': 8, '喜欢': 9, '我': 10, '名字': 12, '他': 11, '猫': 5, '狗': 7, '好': 3, '蜘蛛': 1}
13
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
2019-12-03 09:01:28.925616: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
the real length of each sample [2 2 2 2 2 3]
Epoch: 1000 cost = 1.449701
Epoch: 2000 cost = 1.278301
Epoch: 3000 cost = 1.219589
Epoch: 4000 cost = 1.191665
Epoch: 5000 cost = 1.175023
Epoch: 6000 cost = 1.163936
Epoch: 7000 cost = 1.156038
Epoch: 8000 cost = 1.150135
Epoch: 9000 cost = 1.145562
Epoch: 10000 cost = 1.141918
Epoch: 11000 cost = 1.138948
Epoch: 12000 cost = 1.136482
Epoch: 13000 cost = 1.134402
Epoch: 14000 cost = 1.132625
Epoch: 15000 cost = 1.131089
Epoch: 16000 cost = 1.129749
Epoch: 17000 cost = 1.128569
Epoch: 18000 cost = 1.127523
Epoch: 19000 cost = 1.126589
Epoch: 20000 cost = 1.125750
Epoch: 21000 cost = 1.124992
Epoch: 22000 cost = 1.124305
Epoch: 23000 cost = 1.123678
Epoch: 24000 cost = 1.123104
Epoch: 25000 cost = 1.122577
Epoch: 26000 cost = 1.122091
Epoch: 27000 cost = 1.121641
Epoch: 28000 cost = 1.121225
Epoch: 29000 cost = 1.120837
Epoch: 30000 cost = 1.120475
Epoch: 31000 cost = 1.120138
Epoch: 32000 cost = 1.119821
Epoch: 33000 cost = 1.119524
Epoch: 34000 cost = 1.119245
Epoch: 35000 cost = 1.118982
Epoch: 36000 cost = 1.118734
Epoch: 37000 cost = 1.118499
Epoch: 38000 cost = 1.118277
Epoch: 39000 cost = 1.118066
Epoch: 40000 cost = 1.117866
Epoch: 41000 cost = 1.117676
Epoch: 42000 cost = 1.117495
Epoch: 43000 cost = 1.117323
Epoch: 44000 cost = 1.117159
Epoch: 45000 cost = 1.117001
Epoch: 46000 cost = 1.116851
Epoch: 47000 cost = 1.116707
Epoch: 48000 cost = 1.116570
Epoch: 49000 cost = 1.116438
Epoch: 50000 cost = 1.116311
[7 7 7 7 7 4]
['狗', '狗', '狗', '狗', '狗', '小明']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Moreover, I remove the parameter **sequence_length** and fill the shorter sentences with padding zeros. The loss can go down to nearly 0 easily. And the prediction results of the model are accurate. The resutls are below.

```
Loading model cost 0.601 seconds.
Prefix dict has been built succesfully.
['大家', '讨厌', '狗']
['我', '讨厌', '蜘蛛']
['他', '喜欢', '狗']
['他', '语文', '好']
['我', '喜欢', '猫']
['他', '名字', '是', '小明']
{'蜘蛛': 0, '喜欢': 3, '狗': 2, '名字': 4, '猫': 6, '是': 5, '小明': 7, '大家': 8, '讨厌': 9, '好': 10, '他': 1, '语文': 11, '我': 12}
13
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
2019-12-03 09:08:53.827053: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
the real length of each sample [2 2 2 2 2 3]
Epoch: 1000 cost = 0.066504
Epoch: 2000 cost = 0.028987
Epoch: 3000 cost = 0.018541
Epoch: 4000 cost = 0.013653
Epoch: 5000 cost = 0.010820
Epoch: 6000 cost = 0.008968
Epoch: 7000 cost = 0.007663
Epoch: 8000 cost = 0.006693
Epoch: 9000 cost = 0.005943
Epoch: 10000 cost = 0.005346
Epoch: 11000 cost = 0.004859
Epoch: 12000 cost = 0.004455
Epoch: 13000 cost = 0.004113
Epoch: 14000 cost = 0.003820
Epoch: 15000 cost = 0.003567
Epoch: 16000 cost = 0.003345
Epoch: 17000 cost = 0.003150
Epoch: 18000 cost = 0.002976
Epoch: 19000 cost = 0.002821
Epoch: 20000 cost = 0.002681
Epoch: 21000 cost = 0.002555
Epoch: 22000 cost = 0.002440
Epoch: 23000 cost = 0.002335
Epoch: 24000 cost = 0.002239
Epoch: 25000 cost = 0.002150
Epoch: 26000 cost = 0.002069
Epoch: 27000 cost = 0.001993
Epoch: 28000 cost = 0.001922
Epoch: 29000 cost = 0.001857
Epoch: 30000 cost = 0.001796
Epoch: 31000 cost = 0.001739
Epoch: 32000 cost = 0.001685
Epoch: 33000 cost = 0.001635
Epoch: 34000 cost = 0.001587
Epoch: 35000 cost = 0.001542
Epoch: 36000 cost = 0.001500
Epoch: 37000 cost = 0.001460
Epoch: 38000 cost = 0.001422
Epoch: 39000 cost = 0.001386
Epoch: 40000 cost = 0.001352
Epoch: 41000 cost = 0.001319
Epoch: 42000 cost = 0.001288
Epoch: 43000 cost = 0.001259
Epoch: 44000 cost = 0.001231
Epoch: 45000 cost = 0.001204
Epoch: 46000 cost = 0.001178
Epoch: 47000 cost = 0.001153
Epoch: 48000 cost = 0.001129
Epoch: 49000 cost = 0.001107
Epoch: 50000 cost = 0.001085
[ 2  0  2 10  6  7]
['狗', '蜘蛛', '狗', '好', '猫', '小明']
```

It works fine but it's unresonable to do so. Because filling with padding zeros without using the parameter **sequence_length** means the extra zeros will be treated as normal zeros, which have a real meaning. The number zero represents a word. When I do so, for example, the sentence "大家讨厌狗" will be treated as "大家讨厌?狗" where the question mark "?" equals to the word id2word[0].

Comment: Please strip out all unnecessary parts of the code, and either translate or remove comments not in English.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but you can get rid of that `tf.transpose(...)` line by using the `time_major == True` argument to the RNN.

Comment: Another point is that, `0.01` learning rate for `Adam` raises an alarm in my head. Have you tried the defaults?

Comment: @thushv89 I set the learning rate to 0.001  and 0.0001, the problem still exists.

Comment: @tensory And why do you believe the loss is not going down? I can see it's going down. You shouldn't expect the loss to go down the same way when using variable length, because now the optimization happens differently (e.g. ignoring zeros).

Comment: @thushv89 The max training steps I set in the above code is 5000, and you can see the loss keeps going down. But it is too slow. When I set it to 50000, the loss is still going down but far away from zero.I've added the resuts of max training steps of 50000  at the end of this question.